# Difficulties with trigonometry question - please tell me there's a better way

Tags: trigonometry

Can anyone answer my two questions below (see bold). They are based on a problem a friend recently asked me to have a look at from an engineering exam he must take. In essence: I think I can do the problem but my solution is so ugly and long-winded that I'm convinced there's a better approach.

**The problem**

You are asked to find the values of x and y for the given geometry.

[image]

I believe I managed to solve the problem by setting up simultaneous equations involving x and y using Pythagoras' theorem as follows:

$$
x^2 + (30-y)^2 = 32^2  \;\;(1) \\
(72-x)^2 + y^2 = 48^2  \;\;(2)
$$

**To solve this** I did the following:

- Expand out the equations
- Solve (2) for x as a function of y using the quadratic formula
- Subtract (2) from (1) to eliminate the factor x^2
- Substitute in the expression x(y)
- Solve for y
- Substitute y into the expression for x(y) to get x
- Choose the positive / negative roots appropriately to match the geometry of the question - meaning you don't have lengths greater than possible based on the image and the internal angle between the 32cm and 48cm rod is less than 180 degrees.

This gave me answers of x = 31.8cm and y = 26.2cm.

**My two questions based on this**

1. Is this correct? I've run sanity checks but there was so much algebra (involving huge numbers squared etc) it seemed a miracle my answer appears to have come out correct.
2. Is there a better way of doing it than described above? My solution was a total mess - I had to carry around terms like $7364^2$ and I don't think this particular exam would have intended to be so arithmetically challenging (i.e. requires more persistence and carefulness than a good understanding of concepts).

Thanks for any insight anyone may have.

Comment: WolframAlpha says there are two solutions. One of them is what you have (correct). Yes this calculation is a mess trying to do it by hand whichever way you do it - Pythagoras or trigonometry. The immediate subtraction gives $144x-60y=3004$ which is not "nice" to start with.

Comment: That's the way I'ld do it as well: the difference of two circles is a line.